# Powershell access a single value in a table

Tags: powershell

this should be a really easy one but I can't seem to find an easy way.

For example, in Powershell and am using a CSV file, which is then used to look up some configuration data based on an ID. Here is what I have now, it works, but there has got to be a better way.

```
$configList = import-csv "C:\myconfig.csv"
$id = "5001"

$configList | where-object {$_.id -eq $id} | foreach-object{ $configData = $_.configData}
```

If use format-table etc, I always get the column header, which I would then have to cut off.

Again, this has got to be really easy and this isn't a show stopper. But there has to be a better way to get just the data out of a table without the column header.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this helps but you can load the csv file into an array and then using indices access the individual rows and for each row you can use the column name to access the individual cell.

```
$a = @(Import-CSV C:\myconfig.csv)
$a[0].ColA
```

Just change 'ColA' for the name of your column and remember rows are 0 indexed.

Answer (score 4):

I know of two ways.

```
$configList | where {$_.id -eq $id} | foreach { $_.configData }

$configList | where {$_.id -eq $id} | select -ExpandProperty configData
```

(Style-wise, although I avoid aliases in scripts for clarity, I'm fine with `where`, `foreach`, and `select`, as I don't think that `-Object` adds anything.)

Answer (score 1):

```
| Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

That's the easiest way.